# Why my server restarts unexpectedly?

Tags: windows-server-2008, unexpected-shutdown

I have a server with Windows Server 2008 installed on it.

From time to time it restarts unexpectedly. I see this log after it is manually started after failure:

```
The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.
```

with details:

```
    EventData 

  BugcheckCode 0 
  BugcheckParameter1 0x0 
  BugcheckParameter2 0x0 
  BugcheckParameter3 0x0 
  BugcheckParameter4 0x0 
  SleepInProgress false 
  PowerButtonTimestamp 0
```

Do you see anything which can tell me the cause, here? I am a programmer not a system admin and I am kind of lost. Can you please tell me what should I look for additionally to find the cause of the failure?

**UPDATE**: The last log in System section I see before the shutdown is:

```
A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction response from the UmRdpService service.
```

Comment: Anything in the logs? (Run > `Eventvwr.exe`)

Comment: Run memtest86 on it

Answer (score 1):

> I have a server with Windows Server 2008 installed on it.
>
> From time to time it restarts unexpectedly

Check drivers. Crappy drivers create windows cracshes. If that does not work, ask for replacement / call in technician because you have faulty hardware.

From bad power supply, overheatingCPU and faulty RAM - all that can cause bluescreens.

Current windows is stable. Unless you have bad drivers (posible with 2008 if you got early network drivers, for example, and never updated them - MS changed the droiver model and some of the early drivers were CRAP) or defective hardware it WILL NOT BLUE SCREEEN.

If it is a hardware problem, you need an experienced sysadmin or technician to diagnose it - preferably with a lab so he can start trial and error replacements. Memory is a likely cuplrit, assuming you do not use server hardware (i.e. this is non ECC memory).